# Access ViewModel variables on dispatch event

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This is a ZF2 question.

I'm trying to change my template, depending on a variable setted on my controller (since is there that im going to decide which template use).
In my module onBooststrap i have:

```
$this->eventManager->attach('dispatch', function($e)
    {
        if (0 === strpos($e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller'), __NAMESPACE__, 0))
        {
            $e->getViewModel()->setTemplate('layout');
        }

    }, -100);
```

and in my controller:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction ()
    {
        $view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
        $view->setVariable("layout", "layout");
        return $view;
    }
}
```

but, how do i get access to that view variable "layout", so i can change it in the dispatch event on setTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `onDispatch` method and the `MvcEvent` class it seems there is a `getResult()` method, this may contain the result from the controller action.

Otherwise have you looked at the layout controller plugin? This plugin would allow you to change the template:

```
$this->layout('new layout');
```

Of course this would need to be inside the controller and most likely require adding the template into the template map.