# possible ways to increase performance in ZF2 applications?

Tags: php, performance, benchmarking, zend-framework2

i read a lot benchmark weblog posts about ZF2 that says zf2 has a low performance for response time because of huge functions load and class loads ...

so i need a list of possible ways to increase zf2 performance

thanks

Comment: possible ways to increase zf2 PERFORMANCE is the keyword

Comment: Requesting list answers and the ensuing debates is generally against the Q&A format.

Comment: @Ignas search that keyword in google and see my question is top result

Comment: @Orbling you tell me how should i ask it?

Comment: @SinaMiandashti: My point is, it's not an SO type of question, as it needs a list to answer it and is very broad.  You would need to refine it to a more specific point I think.  However, no one else has put in a close request, so you appear safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Learn about the classmap_autoload.php
- Always return [fully qualified ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178632/zend-framework-2-auto-disable-layout-for-ajax-calls)
- Use something like memcached or APC (always a massive speed boost for frameworks)
- Cache heavy objects
- Keep Module.php light

That's all i can come up with on a quick view other than that, google helps a lot, too